# The Temp table multi-part identifier could not be bound.

Tags: sql, sql-server, dapper

I create a query in c# like this:

```
create table #IdentityPerson (Id int)
insert into [IdentityPerson] (...)
output inserted.Id into #IdentityPerson
values (...)

create table #Identity (Id int)
insert into [Identity] (PersonId,...)
output inserted.Id into #Identity
values (#IdentityPerson.id,...)

create table #IdentityState (Id int)
create table #IdentityCity (Id int)
insert into [IdentityState] (...)
output inserted.Id into #IdentityState
values (...)
insert into [IdentityCity] (StateId,...)
output inserted.Id into #IdentityCity
values (#IdentityState.id,...)

insert into [IdentityAddress] (CityId,IdentityId,...)
values (#IdentityCity.id,#Identity.id,...)

drop table #IdentityCity
drop table #IdentityState
drop table #Identity
drop table #IdentityPerson
```

When I run this query with Dapper.net (ExecuteAsync) I get some `SqlException` errors:

> The multi-part identifier "#IdentityPerson.id" could not be bound. 
>   The multi-part identifier "#IdentityState.id" could not be bound. The
>   multi-part identifier "#IdentityCity.id" could not be bound. The
>   multi-part identifier "#Identity.id" could not be bound.

Anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `insert . . . select`:

```
create table #Identity (Id int);

insert into [Identity] (PersonId,...)
    output inserted.Id into #Identity
    select ip.id, . . .
    from #IdentityPerson ip;
```